# Retag [internet] [explorer] → [internet-explorer]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request

After seeing a question tagged with these two separate tags, I noticed that there are [88 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet+explorer) at the moment tagged that way.

I think they should be retagged (and yes, I'm willing to help, but not within the next ±12 hours, as I really need some sleep now).

Comment: I started knocking some of them off, I'll do some more later if I get a chance.

Comment: I'm also doing a few.

Comment: I've just done the 60 or so that i could see with my *ignored tags* settings. I must have no life.....

Comment: Thanks @slugster and @Tim (who is not called by this second *@userName*, I know), I've just done the last 8.

Answer (score 1):

OK, but in the future contacting a moderator might be the best way to accomplish this...

Comment: Were the mod tools enhanced to handle this case of [a] + [b] --> [c]? If so, excellent!