# How do you review mass tag edits by one user?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I've seen this a few times now but so far I skipped such suggested edits, because I'm unsure what to do.

Right now in the "Suggested Edits" queue, there are a bunch of questions where the tags [internet](/questions/tagged/internet) and [explorer](/questions/tagged/explorer) are replaced by [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer). These are all suggested by the same user.

Assuming that the questions themselves don't require improvements, how should I review these suggested edits?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71227/retag-internet-explorer-internet-explorer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd ignore the fact they were suggested by a single user. Treat each of them individually.

The change the user is making is correct; [internet](/questions/tagged/internet) refers to the Internet, and [explorer](/questions/tagged/explorer) refers to `explorer.exe` in Windows.

However, the thing to be careful here is that the user is fixing *all* substantial issues in the post. If they're editing blatantly poor posts and only fixing the tags (smearing lipstick on a pig), reject the edit for being "too minor".

If however, there is little else to improve in the post, I'd "approve" it; the edits *do* need making; the questions are incorrectly tagged.

Answer (score 9):

Find an edit that was approved (if many are being made, chances are at least one was approved.) Edit it to fix any other errors that were ignored. Then @ comment the edit-suggester. This will appear not to work, because you won't get autocomplete, but it will work and the edit-suggester will be notified. Say something like "I've corrected some issues in this post that you overlooked when you retagged. Because your suggestions need to be reviewed, please fix all the issues in a post when you suggest edits."

In my experience about half of them reply with an angry comment saying they were just trying to help and they don't have to fix everything, but about half immediately change their ways. It is the absolutely fastest and most successful way to get edit-suggesters to behave differently.

Comment: I wish there was a more direct way of communicating with the editors rather than having to use @-comment to alert them of non-ideal editing habits.

Comment: I wish there was any way of communicating with users rather than having to use @-comment.