# Please stop this suggested edit annoyance

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, retag-request

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881229/kara?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) has suggested a ridiculous number of re-tag edits in the last few minutes.

Changing [internet] [explorer] to [internet-explorer]

Normally I wouldn't mind some one going on a cleaning spree, but the majority of the posts in question have several issues that went unchecked.

Most of the ones that I rejected had obvious "thanks" and signature lines.

I've already burned through my 20 Suggested Edit reviews for the day, please help.

Comment: I've been improving and rejecting but yes, it's getting annoying. Having said that it's good retagging and it's valuable to the site; they just need some guidance on what to do better..., e.g. (I hope) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820327/prestashop-target-error-validation/17820439#comment26130875_17820439

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190608/how-do-you-review-mass-tag-edits-by-one-user and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71227/retag-internet-explorer-internet-explorer

Comment: What do you want me to say? This does feel like whoring but the re-tagging _is_ substantially helpful - he is correcting incorrect tags with correct ones.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - What strikes you as odd about that review history? They flagged non-answers that they saw (which I don't believe show up there anymore once they're removed) as well as off-topic questions, and I saw nothing horrible in what they approved. They're doing a much better job than a lot of other people I've seen lately.

Comment: Yesterday that user did the same with the "web" and "design" tags

Comment: "did the same with the "web" and "design" tags" -- Excellent. People should be assisting him instead of trying to hinder him.

Comment: And this is exactly why the retag priv shouldn't have been removed ... Valuable edits get shot down because they go through the queue (and are quite annoying there).

Comment: @GEOCHET One of the reasons for rejecting an edit is "too minor". You could argue that it shouldn't be a reject reason, but it is, and many (most?) of those retags are in fact too minor. That's the problem.

Comment: @bfavaretto however, retagging used to be an actual privilege.

Comment: 'too minor'? How can a retag be 'too minor'? WTF

Answer (score 6):

Retagging is not wrong or abusive to the site. The user is contributing value to the site.

If you can't keep up then just ignore it. No one said you have to do everything yourself.

Rejecting them is actually a significant problem since you are destroying his efforts to improve the site. Why didn't you just edit whatever other obvious aspects that needed to be corrected instead?

This history is far more disturbing to me:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1947286/apaul34208?tab=activity

```
55m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on tried every browser,none will open a dating site called fling.com
56m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on Ember.js: Passing a template's current context object to an action
56m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on Accessing Audio Files in IE
57m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on why this code dont work on firefox
57m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on Color of the text cursor in an input field always takes black in IE?
57m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on Iframe in Internet Explorer Quirks mode will not render at 100% width
57m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on IE8 Block elements with width/height not detecting a mouseover until text inside is hovered
57m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on Navigation bar not displaying well in IE6,7,8 but works on 9 and all other browsers
58m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on Why does IE not display position:absolute like it's supposed to?
58m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on How to css html to display image in IE, which can be viewed in firefox, chrome, and safari?
59m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on Page works fine in Chrome,FF, completely left aligned in IE
59m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on Tool for measuring html-rendering time
59m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on Internet explorer margin auto doesn't work
59m
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on Internet Explorer rejecting my fonts in HTML AND CSS
1h
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on How do I counteract Internet Explorer's way of positioning things?
1h
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on IE 7 adding extra height on table
1h
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on getting flicker with ie7 + when dynamically change background-color on body when using a transparent background image
1h
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on Internet Explorer 7 CSS
1h
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on Internet Explorer 7 error
1h
reviewed    Reject suggested edit on Blue border around image maps in Internet Explorer 9
```

Comment: It's _highly_ recommended you improve the retags, though.

Comment: "Changing [internet] [explorer] to [internet-explorer]" -- How is that not an improvement?

Comment: I don't disagree. I mean to say, improve the contents of the post in any way possible.

Comment: I'm not opposed to re-tagging, I'm opposed to seeing dozens of suggested edits that only address one of the many problems with the posts. Re-tag on just fix the other issues while your at it

Comment: "improve the contents of the post in any way possible" -- Why? Why does there have to be some mandate of a minimum threshold for editing?  Why not appreciate the fact that this guy is burning calories and time to improve the overall content of the site?

Comment: "opposed to seeing dozens of suggested edits that only address one of the many problems with the posts." -- Then edit them.

Comment: If you aren't improving a post that fixes issues in the post but not all, you are not reviewing fairly, or are just being lazy (you are also being harmful to the site by review-ban-striking people who try to help...). They should not be rejected, but improved.